# Alarm not triggering

Tags: android, android-alarms

I've worked with alarms many times, but I can't for the life of me get this to trigger... What am i doing wrong? I've tried triggering Services, BroadcastReceivers, everything. I've tried triggering it from an earlier time and in the future (5 seconds from now). As far as i know it's being set, It's not throwing an error and my log is firing... But nothing in AlarmReceiver is getting triggered.

```
public void setAlarm() {
            Calendar exp = Calendar.getInstance();
            exp.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, exp.getTimeInMillis(),  PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class), 0));
            Log.i("", "Alarm set for " + DateFormat.format("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mma", exp.getTime()));

        }

    }
```

---

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("", "onBind Tiggered");
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("", "onCreate Triggered");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add your Service to your Manifest!!

Answer (score 0):

The time will only be in the future if you run this in the first 5 seconds of a minute.

You should use `calendar.add(field, value);` to add to the time.

If you're in a time zone except GMT, that might also be throwing Calendar off.

To set an alarm for 5 seconds time, it easiest to do it like this:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Ok, true..  but i tried using System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000) with no success.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the log? Can you post the relevant section?

Comment: nope.. nothing happening in the log at all other than what i post to it when i create the alarm

Comment: Is your service defined in your Manifest?

Comment: No. Of course not.... :) That fixed it. Thanks! That's always my number one bug.. But usually I get a error in the logcat. Make a new answer if you want and i'll accept it.

Comment: LOL I make that mistake (and permissions too) so often that I've got a post-it note in big letters that says "DOH XMLs !!"

Comment: @howard pautz not a bad idea!